# How to combine an imageview with some text in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

So far I've been using a simple `ArrayAdapter` to display some items in a `ListView`. Now I also want to display images alongside the text in the `ListView`. I have an `AsyncTask` called   `DownloadImageTask` to download images. The downloading is working perfectly, but I don't know how to display an image in the `ListView` and how to use the `DownloadImageTask` to download the images in the `ListView`.

This is the `DownloadImageTask` I use to download images into an `ImageView`:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

I have also defined an `ImageView` alongside the `ListView` to download the images into the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I call the `DownloadImageTask` like this:

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1)).execute(url);
```

How can I use the `DownloadImageTask` to download images and display them in the `ListView` alongside the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do you have to create a custom `Adapter`. To download the images I suggest you use a library like [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Picasso takes care of pretty much everything when downloading the images and it really can't get any easier to use it, you just need to call this to download an image into an `ImageView`:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

It already caches images and can also transform images in many ways. Picasso is a very powerful yet easy to use library.

---

## 1) Implementing a custom `Adapter`

First we need to create a layout for each row in the `ListView`, in your case since you want to display an image and a text it needs to contain a `TextView` and an `ImageView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now we need to create a container class - called view model - to hold the data which belongs in each row of the `ListView`. In your case this view model contains the text you want to display and the url to the image:

```
private class ExampleViewModel {
    private String text;
    private String imageUrl;

    private ExampleViewModel(String text, String imageUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

`ListViews` use view recycling. We can speed up the performance of the `ListView` by using a pattern called "view holder". Basically we save a reference to the `Views` inside each row and attach it to the row itself. That way we need to call the expensive `findViewById()` only once. This view holder class - I like to call them rows - also contain a method called `bind()` to bind the data from the view model to the `Views` in each row. We need a reference to the `TextView` and `ImageView` but we also need a `Context` for Picasso. I also like to define the layout associated with this row as a public constant in the row.

```
private class ExampleRow {

    // This is a reference to the layout we defined above
    public static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.list_item;

    private final Context context;
    private final TextView textView;
    private final ImageView imageView;

    private ExampleRow(Context context, View convertView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        this.textView = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void bind(ExampleViewModel exampleViewModel) {
        this.textView.setText(exampleViewModel.getText());
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(exampleViewModel.getImageUrl()).into(this.imageView);
    }
}
```

Finally we need a custom `Adapter` to make this work, it's really nothing special. The only interesting part is in `getView()`. I will comment important parts if necessary:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<ExampleViewModel> viewModels;

    private final Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.viewModels = new ArrayList<ExampleViewModel>();
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, List<ExampleViewModel> viewModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
        this.viewModels = viewModels;
    }

    public List<ExampleViewModel> viewmodels() {
        return this.viewModels;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.viewModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewModel getItem(int position) {
        return this.viewModels.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // We only need to implement this if we have multiple rows with a different layout. All your rows use the same layout so we can just return 0.
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // We get the view model for this position
        final ExampleViewModel viewModel = getItem(position);

        ExampleRow row;
        // If the convertView is null we need to create it
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(ExampleRow.LAYOUT, parent, false);

            // In that case we also need to create a new row and attach it to the newly created View
            row = new ExampleRow(this.context, convertView);
            convertView.setTag(row);
        }

        // After that we get the row associated with this View and bind the view model to it
        row = (ExampleRow) convertView.getTag();
        row.bind(viewModel);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And that's everything you need. It's pretty much a best practice implementation of an `Adapter`. It uses the view holder pattern for extra performance and works perfectly with the view recycling of the `ListView`.  It's fast, concise and easy and leaves little room for errors made by the developer which would otherwise slow the `ListView` down. You have perfect separation between what data you want to display (that's all in the `ExampleViewModel`) and how it is displayed (that's in the `ExampleRow`). The adapter itself doesn't know about either - as it should be!

---

## **2) How to use it**

To use the code above we first need to create the view models which hold the data we want to display:

```
ExampleViewModel firstRow = new ExampleViewModel("First Row". "http://http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Freiburger_Alpen.JPG");    
ExampleViewModel secondRow = new ExampleViewModel("Second Row". "http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/lamborghini_egoista_three_quarter_front_view.jpg");    
ExampleViewModel thirdRow = new ExampleViewModel("Third Row". "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vXnf7GjcXmg/UfJZE9rWc2I/AAAAAAAAGRc/x2CIlHM9IAA/s1600/aphoto49721.jpg");
```

We need to add all those rows into a `List`:

```
List<ExampleViewModel> viewModels = new ArrayList<ExampleViewModel>();
viewModels.add(firstRow);
viewModels.add(secondRow);
viewModels.add(thirdRow);
```

And after that we need to create an instance of the `ExampleAdapter` and pass the `List` of view models in the constructor. Finally we just need to set the `Adapter` to the `ListView`:

```
ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(context, viewModels);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can modify the items displayed in the `ListView` later on with the `viewmodels()` method of the `ExampleAdapter`! You just need to remember to always call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` after modifying the  view models:

```
adapter.viewmodels().remove(0); // Remove first view model
adapter.viewmodels().add(someNewViewModel); // Add some new view model

// Always remember to call this method after modifying the viewmodels.
// This will apply the changes to the ListView. 
// If you forget to call this you will get an exception
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go in details tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not going to look through your whole project and fix it for you. If you have a new problem than ask a new question. Post the link here and I promise I will take a look.

Comment: Ok. The problem is at `ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(context, viewModels);
ListView.setAdapter(adapter);` I get an error there saying     `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setAdapter(ListAdapter) from the type ListView `

Comment: This error means you are in a static method and try to access something which is not static - in your case the `setAdapter()` method. Ask a new question, show the relevant parts of your code and any errors you get and also try to explain what you did so far to solve it. I will take a look at the new question and suggest a solution.

Comment: OK I will ask it later

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external library like Picasso or Universal Image Loader, they will give you a lot of options. Since they manage cache, you will be able to load images from urls or whatever one time and show them in several places.

---

You could try:

I'm not sure, but maybe you could use your DownloadClass inside the getView() method of your list's adapter in the next way:

```
  new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1)){
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {
           //set imageview src with your bitmap }}.execute(url);
        }
    }.execute(archivo,"investigacion");
```

Comment: I was looking for something simple, since I won't have any problems with cache. I mean there will be just a small number of images.

Comment: Where are you calling your new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1)).execute(url);

Comment: You cannot get any simpler that [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It handles everything for you. You use it like this: `Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);` and that's it.

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez from another inner class `onPostExecute` method

Comment: @XaverKapeller And how will I form listview with it then?

Comment: Same way you set the text in the `ListView` inside your `Adapter`.

Comment: You mean as `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(), R.layout.mylist, events);` ?

Comment: I will write an answer now which will explain it.

Comment: @XaverKapeller take your time :)

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez The `DownloadImageTask` he uses is not suited to be used in a `ListView`. View recycling will just mess everything up and it's a lot of work to implement a proper image loader that is capable of being used in a `ListView`. Using [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is the simplest solution if this supposed to work right.

Comment: Picasso/UIL were my first options in the answer